# How to delete useless JSP

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

On the website that I'm developping, I'm using a lot of Ajax calls to display informations.

Theses Ajax Call are as follow :

```
function deleteBookingAjax(rowId) {

$.ajax({
    url : "deleteRent.htm", 
    type : "GET",   
    data : {
        "rentId" : rowId
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    cache : false,
    success : function(response) {

        if(response.error) {
            showPopupMessage(response.error, true);
        } 

    },
    statusCode : {
        500 : function() {
            loggingMessage('Error 500');
            reloadBookingTable();
        },
        404 : function() {
            loggingMessage('Error 404');
            reloadBookingTable();
        }

    }
  });
}
```

To perform this call, I have also Controllers as follow :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteRent.htm")
public String deleteRent(Long rentId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (rentId == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {

        rentService.deleteRent(rentId);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        LOGGER.error(e);
    }

    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SUCCESS);

    return ViewNames.BOOKINGS_PAGE;
}
```

But my problem is that : to perform this Ajax call, I need to create a useless JSP file : *WEB-INF/jsp/deleteRent.jsp*

```
<%@page import="net.****.****.web.controllers.RentControllers"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```

If I don't create theses files, the Ajax call is not working...

When the file is not in the WEB-INF/ The Ajax call returns :

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/deleteRent.htm?rowId=1 404 (Not Found)
```

And the logs are showing :

```
2015-07-31 10:47:39,084 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Could not complete request
javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/WEB-INF/jsp/deleteRent.jsp&quot; not found 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:417)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:384)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
....
```

How can I make it work without theses files (I assume it will be in configurations... but where exactly and how ?), because it's not convinient to have a lot of JSP files but when only few of them have contents...

**EDIT**

Here is the content of my context.xml, if the errror is located there, we never know :

```
<!-- resources exclusions from servlet mapping -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />


<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<context:component-scan base-package="net.****.****.web" />

<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="properties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/META-INF/messages_en.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/jsp directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

    <property name="alwaysInclude" value="true" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: jquery code does not depend on any of your jsp tags

Comment: I know, I mean in my question that if the file does not exist, the Ajax call doesn't work. Doesn't matter of the content of the JSP file (I assume, didn't check but looks logical).

Comment: Try to handle multiple functions with a single JSP if do not like to have many JSP files. But it will may lead to security issues hence the function must be determined in some way by the client. /functions.jsp?action=delrnt&ID=1

Comment: It's indeed a solution, but I would like to be able to just delete them, not merge them into different actions :/

Comment: Edit : add of the DispatcherServlet logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if you are looking for this, but you can include below into your applicationContext.xml or your *****-servlet.xml file.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>
```

Add this into your pom. Now you can return String from your method.

```
<!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Same issue, even with this property, I add in edit my context.xml, maybe the error is located there.

Comment: you need to keep your jsp file in WEB-INF/jsp folder.

Comment: But is has no sense, this file is empty, and all the interesting code (the one who returns a JSON object) is in the Controller.
This file is just there for nothing and I'm almost sure there is a way to remove this file...

Comment: What url you are hitting? And just for testing can you remove `Long rentId` from method input parameters and take out it from request.

Comment: Just read `to perform this Ajax call, I need to create a useless JSP file : WEB-INF/jsp/deleteRent.jsp`, you **need not** create jsp file for ajax call, your controller can directly pass value back to your jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is stupid :) but at least it's fixed now :

Putting : `void` to the function fixed the problem.

I deleted the empty file and working without :).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteRent.htm")
public void deleteRent(Long rentId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

  if (rentId == null) {
    return null;
  }

  try {

    rentService.deleteRent(rentId);

  } catch (Exception e) {

    LOGGER.error(e);
  }

  response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can try it. It will help you to return values to your ajax call.